# How come I cannot access values of self.cleaned_data in my clean function?

Tags: django, django-forms

I wrote a clean function for my Django form. I defined `OPTIONAL_PASSWORD_INPUT` and `OPTIONAL_REPEAT_PASSWORD_INPUT` above as password input fields:

```
class addNewMemberForm(SignUpForm):
    username = forms.SlugField(required=False, 
                   min_length=MIN_USER_NAME, 
                   max_length=MAX_USER_NAME, 
                   label="Username (optional)", 
                   help_text="If left empty, we will generate a username for you."
    )
    password = OPTIONAL_PASSWORD_INPUT
    password2 = OPTIONAL_REPEAT_PASSWORD_INPUT

    def clean(self):

        # if user name is filled out, so must be the password field.
        if self.data["username"] and not self.data["password"]:
            raise forms.ValidationError("If you specify a username, you must specify a password.")

        return self.cleaned_data

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.keyOrder = uniqueify(['username', 'email'] + self.fields.keyOrder)
```

If I change `if self.data["username"] and not self.data["password"]:` to `if self.cleaned_data["username"] and not self.cleaned_data["password"]:`, Django produces a key  error for "username."

Why is it that I can access values of the `self.data` array, but not those of the `self.cleaned_data` array in my clean function?

On another note, does this question even matter? Could I just use `self.data`?

Answer (score 0):

The individual field validation and cleaning is done prior to calling the `form.clean`. `username` is added to the cleaned_data only if the entered data was valid. This means you should either use `self.cleaned_data.get` or check if there are any errors on `self.errors` early in your clean and just bail on the additional validation which might not be necessary if the individual fields are not valid.